# Internet access after the user logs in

Tags: authentication, lan

I am building a web application for cyber cafe users, they need to register to it before using internet. I need to implement a functionality which makes the internet inaccessible to the user before login. (The users log in from computers in a LAN with a single gateway to internet-cafe owner's computer). Help!

Comment: I think this is usually done in the router or switch.